# Internal Server Error

Tags: gack

I have created Custom Custom Multi-Select picklist field in Visualforce as given in the link https://hisrinu.wordpress.com/2011/05/30/custom-multi-select-picklist-field-in-visualforce/. the functionality is working fine but for some cases i was getting the following error.Please provide me the solution.how to resolve this issue.

I am facing the below issue.

> An internal server error has occurred An error has occurred while
>   processing your request. The salesforce.com support team has been
>   notified of the problem. If you believe you have additional
>   information that may be of help in reproducing or correcting the
>   error, please contact Salesforce Support. Please indicate the URL of
>   the page you were requesting, any error id shown on this page as well
>   as any other related information. We apologize for the inconvenience.
>
> Thank you again for your patience and assistance. And thanks for using
>   salesforce.com!
>
> Error ID: 50425390-19699 (-1043758161)

```
<apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label} :"  for="sel1" style="float:left;margin-left:102px" ></apex:outputLabel>
          <apex:selectList id="sel1"   value="{!leftselected}" multiselect="true" size="3" style="width:50px;margin-left: 4px">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!unselectedvalues}" />
            </apex:selectList>

            </apex:outputPanel>
                <apex:outputPanel >
                    <br/>
                    <apex:image value="/s.gif" styleClass="rightArrowIcon" title="add" style="margin-top:-11px">
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!selectclick}" reRender="sel1,Pan2" />
                    </apex:image>
                    <br/><br/>
                     <apex:image value="/s.gif" styleClass="leftArrowIcon" title="remove" >
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!unselectclick}" reRender="sel1,Pan2"/>
                    </apex:image>
                 </apex:outputPanel>
                 <apex:outputPanel id="Pan2">
           <apex:selectList id="sel2" label="{!$Label}" value="{!rightselected}" multiselect="true" style="width:50px" size="3" >
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!SelectedValues}" />
            </apex:selectList>
              </apex:outputPanel>
```

this peice of code is getting an error

Comment: HI Dileep, Welcome to the SE community, Please go through the How to ask section prior to asking any question. The thumb rule of asking any question here is that provide as much detail you can provide. i.e. what steps you are following which is leading to that error. your code because the url you are providing can be down in future. etc.

Comment: @Himanshu, if i remove that particular piece of code,i am not getting internal server error.how to resolve that issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should open Salesforce Support ticket.

Go to https://help.salesforce.com/mysuccesshub?id=solutionFinder

Salesforce Support should investigate your case and give you a reason why you obtain this internal gack

Comment: Everytime I go to the link it ask me to login, so i login using my Developer edition username, and still it will popup the same login page.Is Salesforce Support available for free edition for these type of issue?